# Geoserver Dynamic Raster Masking Based on Request Parameter

Tags: raster, geoserver, masking

Is it possible for Geoserver to dynamically mask out values above or below a certain threshold in a WMS or WCS Geo-tiff request?

For instance I make a request with some threshold parameter like 49 and all values above that get masked out, set to 0, or -9999 (the no data value) in the response.

EDIT -- In response to BRADHARD's comment

With his suggestion I use the following request and SLD as a test:

```
myserver/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&bbox=-125.020833333333,24.0625,-66.479166666662,49.937500000002&srs=EPSG:4269&env=opacity3k:0&layers=gdd:agdd&styles=gdd:agdd_web,&format_options=layout:provisional&width=1800&height=800&time=2016-06-17&format=image/png
```

-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
<NamedLayer>
<Name>agdd</Name>
<UserStyle>
<Name>agdd</Name>
<Title>AGDD</Title>
<FeatureTypeStyle>
<Rule>
<RasterSymbolizer>
<Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
<ColorMap>         
  <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="0" label=""/>
  <ColorMapEntry color="#5e4fa2" quantity="1000" label="1000"/>
  <ColorMapEntry color="#3288bd" quantity="2000" label="2000"/>
  <ColorMapEntry color="#66c2a5" quantity="3000" opacity="${env('opacity3k',1)}" label="3000"/>
  <ColorMapEntry color="#abdda4" quantity="4000" label="4000"/>
  <ColorMapEntry color="#e6f598" quantity="5000" label="5000"/>
  <ColorMapEntry color="#ffffbf" quantity="6000" label="6000"/>
  <ColorMapEntry color="#fee08b" quantity="7000" label="7000"/>
  <ColorMapEntry color="#fdae61" quantity="8000" label="8000"/>
  <ColorMapEntry color="#f46d43" quantity="9000" label="9000"/>
  <ColorMapEntry color="#d53e4f" quantity="10000" label="10000"/>
  <ColorMapEntry color="#9e0142" quantity="11000" label="11000"/>
</ColorMap>
</RasterSymbolizer>
</Rule>
</FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: RasterSymbolizer using CQL expression should do what you want: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/rastersymbolizer.html

Comment: Cool! This kind of works but I have two hurdles. The first is that it doesn't work when I make a WMS request that stacks a vector layer on top of my raster layer. For instance with &layers=gdd:agdd,gdd:states it doesn't work (gdd:states is just state borders) but with &layers=gdd:agdd (only the raster layer) it does work. The second hurdle is that my SLD color ramp has coarse bins and I want the threshold to start masking at any arbitrary integer. I'm editing my question to include my current SLD to give you an idea of what I mean.

Comment: Consider making your data available. Also, the detail in the comment about what does and does not work needs to be in the question, as a _single question_.